# Array, hexadecimal and serial write

Tags: serial, array

I am trying to write a pice of code which send to a receiver the frequency to listen.

As per its documentation, it should receive the following sequence:

> Example with **123.456** MHz
>
> Command to send (frequency converted in 4 bytes, followed by 2 instruction bytes
>
> 0x**12** 0x**23** 0x**56** 0x00 0x01

To be able to memorize six frequencies, I fill an array:

```
uint32_t mem_freq[6] = {
   0x121050,
   0x126500,
   0x120500,
   0x121700,
   0x121825,
   0x118700,
};
```

My concern is that when I do :

```
Serial.write(mem_freq[mem_index]);
//Serial.write(0x00);
//Serial.write(0x01);
```

Only 1 byte is sent, and it's hard to debug as the serial console displays only ascii characters.

When I use Serial.print instead, mem_freq[2] shows correctly 0x120500

After Majenko's answer, I tried this:

```
Serial.print(0x123456 >> 16,HEX);
Serial.print(0x123456 >> 8,HEX);
Serial.print(0x123456,HEX);
Serial.print(0x00,HEX);
Serial.print(0x01,HEX);
```

And it outputs:

> 12123412345601

Is this normal ?

Comment: use Serial.print(value, HEX) to print on Serial Monitor in hex form https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/

Comment: encoding 123.456 as 0x12 0x23 0x56 is very exotic. how do you use the frequency? I would send it as decimal number 123456. It fits into uint32_t

Comment: @Juraj, i think that the receiver hardware uses BCD and requires the above mentioned byte stream for correct operation

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually split your values into bytes. You can either do that by storing them as individual bytes (as shown by Ignacio), or by using bit shifting:

```
Serial.write(mem_freq[mem_index] >> 16);
Serial.write(mem_freq[mem_index] >> 8);
Serial.write(mem_freq[mem_index]);
```

That sends the bits 16-23 (0x12) then bits 8-15 (0x10) followed by bits 0-7 (0x50).

Comment: Thanks Majenko. I have edited my post to show the result in ascii, and it is strange...

Comment: Since you have switched from `write` to `print` it can now print the entire number every time. If you want to print it you should also mask the value with `& 0xFF`.

Comment: `Serial.print((0x123456 >> 16) & 0xFF,HEX);`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to use an array of arrays, and send three bytes.

```
uint32_t mem_freq[6][3] = {
  {0x12, 0x10, 0x50},
   ... 
};

 ...
  Serial.write(mem_freq[mem_index], 3);
 ...
```